# sqlalchemy - Filtering based on child of child

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have three classes: PurchaseOrder, PurchaseOrderLine, Item

PurchaseOrder children are PurchaseOrderLine which is related to Item.

```
pos = DBSession.query(m_po.PO).filter(or_(
            m_po.PO.number == query,
            m_po.POLine.item.code == query
        )).join(m_po.POLine).join(m_im.Item)
```

Gives me ...

```
AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'code'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming:

```
m_po = PurchaseOrder
m_pol = PurchaseOrderLine
m_it = Item
```

and that the relationships are defined between those, you should be able to achieve this as following (not tested):

```
pos = (DBSession.query(m_po.PO).
    join(m_pol, m_po.POLine).
    join(m_it, m_pol.Items).
    filter(or_(
        m_po.PO.number == query,
        m_it.code == query,
    ))
```

*Note: i am somewhat confused what `m_im` in your code stands for*.

Comment: m_po, m_im or the modules that the classes are in. m_po (module purchase order), m_im (module inventory management). I should have explained better either way your answer gave me what i was looking for thanks!